# In the CanFly interface, the speed method must be declared with one argument of type CanFly

Tags: java

In the CanFly interface, the speed method must be declared with one argument of type CanFly and with a return value type of Double.
I don't know what to write in the parameter

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }

    interface CanMove{
        Double speed();
    }

    interface CanFly extends CanMove{
        @Override
        public Double speed();  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do exactly what the assignment is telling you. You add one argument with the type `CanFly` and return a `Double` object.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }

    interface CanMove{
        Double speed();
    }

    interface CanFly extends CanMove{
       public Double speed(CanFly target);  
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to remove the `@Override` annotation since you provide a new overload for the existing `speed()` method from the `CanMove` interface.

Comment: why target. for what?

Comment: @user9545468 It is just a name, you can name it whatever you want.